# What is the inverse of this variant of the Gimli SP-box?

Tags: s-boxes, decryption, permutation, gimli

Consider a slightly modified variant of the [Gimli](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/630) SP-box:

```
function spbox(s) {
    x = s[0];
    y = s[1];
    z = s[2];
    X = x ^ (z << 1) ^ ((x ^ (y | ~z)) << 1);  
    Y = y ^ x ^ ((y ^ (x | z)) << 1);
    Z = z ^ y ^ ((z ^ (x & y)) << 1);
    return [Z, Y, X]
}
```

Here `s` is an array of three $32$-bit words, `^` is the bitwise XOR, `|` is the bitwise OR, `&` is the bitwise AND, `~` is the bitwise NOT, `<<` is the left non-cyclic shift modulo $2^{32}$:

```
~11000000000000000000000000000000 = 00111111111111111111111111111111,
11000000000000000000000000000000 << 1 = 10000000000000000000000000000000.
```

What is the inverse function of `spbox` (in the C-like pseudocode)?

Comment: You can start with unmodified inverse Gimli spbox you can find in https://project.inria.fr/quasymodo/files/2020/05/gimli_cryptanalysis_eprint.tar.gz (invspbox in datatypes.cpp).

Comment: @LightBit: yes, I have seen that `invspbox` function. Based on this information, I tried to write the inverse for the modified `spbox`, but my algorithm did not output the correct results.

Comment: @kelalaka: Proving that this SP-box is invertible is maybe even a bit harder than doing this for the original SP-box, which is already non-trivial. But I computed the `spbox` for all possible triples of 4-bit and 6-bit words (instead of 32-bit words), and it seems that the function is bijective (which implies that it is invertible).

Comment: No,   it can't `Z = z ^ y ^ ((z ^ (x & y)) << 1)` the $&$ make is non-bijective. Consider that when $y=[0,\ldots,0]$ then for any value of $x$ the $(x \& y)$ Is zero. The other values are x-or and shifts that cannot make it bijective.

Comment: @kelalaka: can you give two triples (T1, T2) of 32-bit words (or, say, 4-bit or 16-bit words) such that `spbox(T1)` is equal to `spbox(T2)`? That will prove that the modified SP-box is non-bijective.

Comment: Fix $z=0$ (we still need surjective),  then $Z = y \oplus ((x \& y) << 1)$, now set $y=0$ then $Z = 0$ for any values of $x$

Comment: @kelalaka: I still cannot find two triples of words that evaluate to the same output.

Comment: I suspect Gimli's "invspbox" only works, if shifts are different for each word.

Comment: @LightBit: I tested various combinations of the shift distances; it seems that they do not affect the invertibility. Note that the linked paper contains the following statement: "we searched through many combinations of possible shift distances". This suggests that there is no particular combination that prevents the SP-box from being invertible (assuming that all distances are greater than zero).

Comment: $(1,0,0),(2,0,0)$?

Comment: @kelalaka: I have `spbox([1, 0, 0]) == [0, 3, 4294967293], spbox([2, 0, 0]) == [0, 6, 4294967288]` (for 32-bit words).

Comment: Well,  while we were implementing the cryptography, two people were assigned so that they independently write and compare the steps and results. Sometimes, they stuck in the same error. Do you expect me to find an error in your code or in my (weak) argument? Writing a good code requires testing...

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/rMjWfGosK

Comment: @kelalaka: you asked about $(1, 0, 0)$ and $(2, 0, 0).$ The purpose of my previous comment was to show that they evaluate to two different outputs, as expected for an invertible bijective function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, note that `(z << 1) ^ ((x ^ (y | ~z)) << 1)` can be simplified to the shorter `~(x ^ (y & z)) << 1`.

The trick is to start from the least significant bit. When considering only the least significant bit, we have
$$
\begin{align}
x_0 &= X_0 \\
y_0 &= Y_0 \oplus x_0 \\
z_0 &= Z_0 \oplus y_0 
\end{align}
$$
The next bits are also obtainable similarly by using the newly recovered least significant bits:
$$
\begin{align}
x_i &= X_i \oplus 1 \oplus x_{i-1} \oplus (y_{i-1} \land z_{i-1}) \\
y_i &= Y_i \oplus x_i \oplus y_{i-1} \oplus (x_{i-1} \lor z_{i-1}) \\
z_i &= Z_i \oplus y_i \oplus z_{i-1} \oplus (x_{i-1} \oplus y_{i-1})
\end{align}
$$
Putting this together into pseudocode, we get

```
function ispbox(s) {
    X = s[2];
    Y = s[1];
    Z = s[0];
    x = X & 1;
    y = (Y ^ x) & 1;
    z = (Z ^ y) & 1;
    for(i = 1; i < 32; ++i) {
        x |= (1 << i) & (X ^ ~(x ^ (y & z)) << 1);
        y |= (1 << i) & (Y ^ x ^ (y ^ (x | z)) << 1);
        z |= (1 << i) & (Z ^ y ^ (z ^ (x & y)) << 1);
    }
    return [x,y,z];
}
```